# Difference between tmpList["colName"=="value"] and tmpList["colName"=="value",]

Tags: r

I had a very big list of data in R, and I used the following line:

```
subsetList <- tmpList[tmpList$colName=="value"]
```

Where colName is the name of the column in the list and 'value' is the text I wanted to subset 'tmpList' on.

The result was I received was a complete replication of 'tmpList' in the new list.

After some experimenting, I used the following instead:

```
subsetList <- tmpList[tmpList$colName=="value" , ]
```

(Note the comma inserted.)

Now my 'subsetList' contains only the rows where the content of the column given by 'colName' is matching to "value".

Why does the first attempt return all the rows? And why does the second attempt return only rows matching the equivalence criteria?

Comment: Your second attempt shouldn't have worked neither. There is a missing information here. For example, `mtcars["cyl" == 6,]` won't work althouth there are mathing values in `cyl`

Comment: Whoops. Changed the line the wrong way. Will edit the column name part.

Comment: The edited version works now. I am getting back the required rows.

Comment: The second one is rows subsetting, the first one is a column subsetting and just subsets the columns according the logical vector. This is more or less equivalent to `tmpList[, tmpList$colName=="value"]` because a `data.frame` is actually a list and can be subsetted as such.